# How to fix USB pendrive

Tags: partitioning, usb, usb-drive, gparted

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and my friend gave me a pendrive to repair. When I use GParted it doesn't work, so I went to the information section and then it said this:

warning  unable to detect file system! possible reasons are:

- the file system is damaged
- the file system is unknown to gparted
- there no file system available (unformatted)
- the device entry/dev/sdc1 is missing

The pendrive is a Kingston 32GB pendrive.

Comment: do you need to save a data from this pen drive? Because formatting or partitioning could solve some issues.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the filesystem is damaged , the only option is to format the drive. When I created backup pen drive from a chromebook, something went wrong, so i had to format and create new partition on that pen drive with gparted. You can always try using dd command. More information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29.

If you want to try recover the files there, I would suggest this recovery software: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

or Gzip recovery toolkit (ubuntu software center).

Comment: the files are not important